# Eclipse CDT: No way to add Language Settings Provider

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, ros

I am trying to use ROS with Eclipse and I need to do one of the last steps of the [How to install eclipse and configure it for ROS](https://github.com/ROS-Robotics/Webot-ROS-Setup-Docment/wiki/How-to-install-eclipse-and-configure-it-for-ROS#sudo-gedit-usrshareapplicationseclipsedesktop) instructions:

> Click the tab "Providers" and check the box next to "CDT GCC Built-in
>   Compiler Settings [ Shared ]"

But I couldn't do it:

[image: properties]

Answer (score 0):

In your image, you clicked on the C/C++ Include Paths entry, not the C/C++ General entry; it may be under there, either directly or in a subpage. The article was written in 2017, so compare your version to what Eclipse was in 2017.